# MongoTemplate get query taking much time

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

We are having Mongodb and we are querying data from spring boot application and our existing query is like

```
Query query = new Query();
        List<String> abcIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> xyzIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Request request : searchRequest
                .getabcxyzIds()) {
            abcIdList.add(request.getAbcId());
            xyzIdList.add(request.getXyzId());
        }
        
        query.addCriteria(
                Criteria.where(ObjectEntity.PRACTICE_ID).is(practiceId).and(ObjectEntity.ABC_ID)
                        .in(abcIdList).and(ObjectEntity.XYZ_ID).in(xyzIdList));
        return executeAndLogPerformance("methodname",
                () -> mongoTemplate.find(query, ObjectEntity.class));
```

So this query is taking to much time to get data.
I have tested it for 2000 records to get fetch it's taking around 17-20 seconds.

So is there any other query to simply it and get data quickly?

Comment: Can you paste the resulting MongoDB query?

Comment: @earandap 
{ "practiceId" : "24249", 
    "abcId" : { "$in" : ["88"]}, "xyzId" : { "$in" : ["776756"]}}

Comment: Are you sure your query is taking all that time ? 
What is this piece is doing ? 
```
Request request : searchRequest
                .getabcxyzIds()
```

Comment: Does your collection have any [indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-compound/)?